# Are There Baggage Lockers at the San Francisco International Airport?

Tags: luggage, airports, san-francisco, sfo

My plane from SFO back to Germany leaves at 10 p.m. tonight, I thought I'd take an Uber from my Hotel in San Jose to the airport early, lock up my baggage there and then go downtown to explore the city.

Are there baggage lockers available at the San Francisco International Airport?

If yes, where are they located?

My flight leaves at the International Terminal G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luggage storage services at the San Francisco International Airport are provided by the Airport Travel Agency.

Storage cost for 24 hours ranges from 13-35$ per piece, depending on luggage size

- Location: International Terminal, Pre-Security Main Hall
- Hours of Operation: Daily, 6:00 a.m. to 11:00 p.m.
- Phone: 650.877.0422
- Web: [airport's website](https://www.flysfo.com/services-amenities/airport-travel-agency)